# How does a threadpool deal with high-recursive tasks in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, threadpool, c++20

Hi: I plan to write a threadpool in C++ that allows user to submit tasks and execute. For example on a 8-core machines, ideally 8 workers could execute in parallel.
However, as I think more about it, I find a problem.
Suppose I have a task like computing Fibonacci:

```
int fib(int n) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

If I use the threadpool to do it, I might write code as this:

```
int fib(int n) {
  if (n <= 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  // in form of std::future you can wait upon
  auto fut_n_1 = pool.submit(fib, n-1);
  auto fut_n_2 = pool.submit(fib, n-2);
  return fut_n_1.get() + fut_n_2.get();
}
```

But when the fib(n) is being computed on a thread worker, it spawns two more tasks to be done by other workers. It has to wait on `fut_n_1` and `fut_n_2`. In this way, very quickly **all 8 thread workers are stuck**. Even if we allow to spawn more thread workers, the cost of overscription of threads will deteriorate the system performance quickly.

I am not asking how to "better write  Fibonacci function". I am wondering, how to design threadpool so that you can somehow remember the "context" and yield destroy yourself when dealing with high-recurisve tasks like **quicksort** for example. I've seen some ancient system can do this like **Clik** using **sys_set_jump**. But I don't quite feel like using that too low-level details. **Is there any modern C++ technique that could achieve more or less the same effect?**

I am pasting my current threadpool implementation here for reference:

```
// header file
class ThreadPool {
 public:
  // save one thread for the main
  explicit ThreadPool(int size = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1);

  ~ThreadPool();

  template <typename F, typename... Args>
  decltype(auto) SubmitTask(F &&new_task, Args &&...args);

  void Exit();

  auto GetSize() -> size_t;

 private:
  std::vector<std::thread> threads_;
  std::queue<std::function<void()>> tasks_;
  std::mutex mtx_;
  std::condition_variable cv_;
  std::atomic<bool> exit_{false};
};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto ThreadPool::SubmitTask(F &&new_task, Args &&...args) -> decltype(auto) {
  using return_type = std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>;
  if (exit_) {
    throw std::runtime_error("ThreadPool: SubmitTask() called while already exit_ being true");
  }
  auto packaged_new_task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<return_type()>>(
      std::bind(std::forward<F>(new_task), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  auto fut = packaged_new_task->get_future();
  {
    // submit in form of std::function to the Thread Pool task queue
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
    tasks_.emplace([packaged_new_task]() { (*packaged_new_task)(); });
  }
  cv_.notify_one();
  return fut;
}
}
```

```
// cpp file
ThreadPool::ThreadPool(int size) {
  /* std::thread::hardware_concurrency() might return 0 if sys info not
   * available */
  size = std::max(size, MIN_NUM_THREADS_IN_POOL);
  for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    threads_.emplace_back([this]() {
      while (true) {
        std::function<void()> next_task;
        {
          std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_);
          cv_.wait(lock, [this]() { return exit_ || !tasks_.empty(); });
          if (exit_ && tasks_.empty()) {
            return;  // thread life ends
          }
          next_task = tasks_.front();
          tasks_.pop();
        }
        next_task();
      }
    });
  }
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool() {
  Exit();
  for (auto &worker : threads_) {
    if (worker.joinable()) {
      worker.join();
    }
  }
}

void ThreadPool::Exit() {
  exit_ = true;
  cv_.notify_all();
}

auto ThreadPool::GetSize() -> size_t { return threads_.size(); }
```

Comment: Some tasks are not suitable for multi-threading.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Well, not suitable for "easy threadpool-dispatch-based multithreading" anyway. Arbitrary depth recursion (especially when it's linear depth based on the input) like this being a bad use case. To make it work, the workers themselves would effectively have to be event loops (or structured as a shared event loop of some kind, which I don't even want to think about engineering), with waiting on tasks implicitly descheduling the waiting task on that thread, passing control back to the event loop(s) to do unblocked tasks.

Comment: In the Java code at our work, our solution was to switch to ListenableFutures, and ban Future.get, because of *exactly* this problem.  C++ futures and base Java futures are unsuitable for use with threadpools.

Comment: Cooperative multitasking can come in handy here. C++20 certainly added the building blocks for it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the discussions above. I want to ask about, what exactly is the "Cooperative multi-tasking in C++20" refers to? Which features? Is it co-routine?

Comment: A common rule in thread pools is that no job can depend on any other. This prevents deadlocks and other problems.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about C++.   Its about managing psuedo-threads by multiplexing real ones.

What you want to do is to provide a set of queues, once for each real thread.  The queues are basically sets of work that need to be done, e.g., its a list of continuations (implemented by storing machine state (PC, ESP, ...).

Then whenever a part of program wants to fork, the "fork"ed code's continuation is placed on the thread queue.   This is a small block that is allocated by a per-thread allocator so it is very fast.

When a program runs out of work, the underlying thread checks its queue, and if it contains something, that continuation is extracted from the queue and the thread "becomes" that continuation (typically means loading key registers, PC, ESP, ...)

If a thread's queue is empty, it must steal work from another thread's queue.  Yes, that means locks around the queues.    If it finds no work in any queue, then the thread can go to sleep for varying intervals, and then repeat checking its queue, and other queues.

Without any controls, this might produce lots of continuations.  Millions shouldn't be a problem but that does use a lot of memory and then the cache behavior is not as nice as you'd like.

But if you need a limit on size, then the fork logic simply checks the queue size;  if greater than a threshold, it simply *calls* the "forked" code, and on return, executes the continuation of the forking code.

The concept and implementation details you want are called "work stealing scheduler"; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing.   Cilk (not Clik) does this too.

You might find this paper interesting; it describes a language, PARLANSE, that does this: http://semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/Parallelism-in-symbolic-computation.pdf

Here's your fibonacci function in PARLANSE (yes, this really runs):

```
(define fibonacci
   (lambda (function natural natural )function 
   `Given n, computes nth fibonacci number'
   (ifthenelse (<= ? 1)
               ?
               (let (;; [n natural ] [m natural ]  )
                       (value (|| (= m (fibonacci (-- ?)) )=
                                  (= n (fibonacci (- ? 2)) )=
                              )||
                              (+ m n)
                       )value
               )let
   )ifthenelse  
   )lambda
)define
```

The "(|| ... )||" operator says "run these in parallel".  All the interesting machinery to support forking/managing queues is in the PARLANSE runtime system, and is invoked by calls from the PARLANSE compiler when it encounters the parallel operator.

We run this as a toy/test, often as (fibonacci 45) which would produce rather a lot of parallel grains.  The PARLANSE runtime limits the queue sizes to a modest number like 16.   This runs in parallel with small queues.

fibonacci done this way isn't terribly efficient, because the amount of work per forked grain is pretty small, and the work to manage the grain swamps the advantage of the parallelism.  But if you implement recursive sorting and terminate the recursion when sorting small lists (say, size 8 or more) then the  parallelism works quite well.